# Kodi (fka Xbmc) scraper for onlinetvrecorder (otr) recordings

Tags: kodi

I would like scrape information for recordings from [onlinetvrecorder (otr)](http://www.onlinetvrecorder.com) in [Kodi](http://kodi.tv/). Unfortunately the scrapers available can't handle the file format which is like

> Django_Unchained_15.07.03_22-45_sf2_165_TVOON_DE.mpg.mp4.avi

Renaming is not an option, since the filename is a key for otr. I know there is a scraper called [xbmc-otr](https://github.com/gibro/xbmc-otr), but it never left beta status and seems to be outdated.

Any suggestions, on how to correctly display those files in Kodi?
Has anybody written or started a scraper for otr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found a solution to the problem. Put the following in %appdata%\Kodi\userdata\advancedsettings.xml ([advancedsettings.xml](http://kodi.wiki/view/Advancedsettings.xml) does not exist in advance, you have to create it)

```
<advancedsettings>
  <video>
    <cleanstrings action="prepend">
     <regexp>_\d\d\.[0-1]\d\.[0-3]\d_[0-2]\d-[0-5]\d_</regexp>
    </cleanstrings>
  </video>
</advancedsettings>
```

The regexp `<regexp>_\d\d\.[0-1]\d\.[0-3]\d_[0-2]\d-[0-5]\d_</regexp>` matches the timestamp in the otr filename, so that everything right of the match (at the end of the file name) is removed. See the [official Kodi documentation](http://kodi.wiki/view/Advancedsettings.xml#cleanstrings) for further reference. The remaining file name can be handled by the scrapers shipped with Kodi.
Despite of the relatively coarse regexp I added, all my otr movies were recognized correctly.

The solution is tested with Kodi 15.2 (Isengard), but should work with all versions that support the cleanstrings option.

EDIT:

A similar soltuion works for TV Shows. The only requirement is that the file name contains season and episode information like S01E02 for example.

```
<tvshowmatching action="prepend">
    <regexp>_[Ss]([0-9]+)[Ee]([0-9]+)([^\\/_]*)</regexp>
</tvshowmatching>
```